# Rules in Halacha

Tags: halacha-theory

I know in general we rule l'halacha like Beis Hillel except in a few cases. I know there are other rules where one rabbis rulings top another's in general (not referring because of the era they are from) would someone be able to provide a list of these?

Comment: They are scattered internally throughout the Talmud. Even then, later codifiers, besides following these and other traditions as whom to follow, they also made use of their own judicial prowess to decide the law. Indeed and in fact such ability is part of the very fabric of Jewish law and is thus available today and always to those who have reached such heights and conferred status.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel there are at least three related questions on MY which mention that reference these laws, but is there any place/text/website that collects them all in one list?

Comment: @rosends What comes to mind is the fact that there is a vast literature known as *klalim*, thus many great rabbis have gathered these into there books. But in our times the best of the best is Rabbi Yitzhak Yoseph's three volume *ein Yitzhak*, and it is available on hebrewbooks. I can't add more right now; mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Mi Yodea.
Take a look at the ones listed on [Halachipedia's Klalei HaPoskim pages](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Klalei_HaPoskim)
In general, there are some sefarim that do this really well, depending on whether you're looking into Tannaim and Amoraim, Rishonim, etc. See the further reading section there for a list of them.

Comment: Remember also that all rules have exceptions so they have to be applied carefully

Comment: I went through the pedia page and looked at the links to further reading and don;t see any sort of accumulated list of talmudic policies/rules (in an argument about X, we generally hold like Rav Y, or when Rav X argues with Rav Y the halacha is like Rav Y). Does that kind of list exist?

Comment: Yes, https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Klalei_HaTalmud